# Changing the data type from String to Date in the QuickSight dataset editor

Tags: string, date, dataset, amazon-quicksight

I have a dataset based on some DynamoDB table data. It includes a string column named "Deploy_DateTime", which contains values like these:

```
"2023-06-21T09:55:00Z"
"2023-06-21T15:32:53Z UTC"
"NA"
```

There are two types of dates in this column: those with and without the "UTC" portion. If there is no date available, the column displays "NA".

Now, when I attempt to change the data type to "Date", I am unable to find a date format that accommodates all possible values.

The following format works only for values with the "UTC" portion:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z' 'UTC'
```

Is there a format that would work for all values in this column? In the case of "NA," we could use a default value of "1970-01-01" if we need to assign a date to each column.

Alternatively, is it possible to create a calculated field and convert it to a Date? If so, what would be the formula for creating such a calculated field?

Comment: Ok, so I was able to create a calculated field based on "Deploy_DateTime" field. The formula is the following:

`ifelse({Deploy_DateTime} = 'NA', NULL, parseDate(left({Deploy_DateTime}, 19), 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss'))`

Which results into dates like:

`2023-07-04T15:57:02.000Z`

And that is what I wanted. However, in QuickSight's analysis using this calculated field, there are no hours and minutes available, even when using the formatting to include the HH:mm part. Any thoughts on that?